# How to iterate over dictionary of array values to render components? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to iterate over a dictionary of arrays of nodes but am having trouble rendering the components. It compiles and builds correctly but none of the rendering is happening.

It should iterate through `'values'` with the dictionary and go through every array and render the elements in the array and do that for all the arrays in the dictionary. I'm not sure why I can't seem to get that to work...

```
var props = {
    'name' : 'form',
    'timer' : 1500,
    'callback' : function(id, validity, value) {console.log(id, validity, value);},
    'values': {
        "1": ["hello", "world"],
        "2": ["", "test"],
        "3": ["i", "am", "me"]
    },

    'hashNode' : new FormatOC.HashNode({
        "__hash__":true,
        "__array__":"duplicate",
        "__type__":"string"
    }),
}

React.render(React.createElement(HashNodeComponent, props), document.getElementById('react-component'));
```

**hash node:**

```
    render: function() {
        var that = this;

        console.log("Dict:", this.state.values);

        var dict = that.state.values;

        return (
            <div id = "form">
                {Object.keys(dict).map(function(key, index) {
                    console.log("Arrays:", dict[key]);

                    dict[key].map(function(v, i) {
                        return (
                            <div>
                            {(that.props.hashNode.get().constructor.name === "Parent") ?                                 
                                    <ParentComponent
                                        name={that.props.name + i}
                                        key={i}
                                        timer={that.props.timer}
                                        callback={that.childChange}
                                        values={v}
                                        newParent={that.props.hashNode.get()}
                                    />
                                    :
                                    <NodeComponent
                                        name={that.props.name + i}
                                        key={i}
                                        timer={that.props.timer}
                                        callback={that.childChange}
                                        value={v}
                                        newNode={that.props.hashNode.get()}
                                    />
                                }
                                <button data-index={i} onClick={that.removeItem}>Remove
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                })
                <button onClick={() => that.addEmptyItem()}>Add
                </button>
            }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return in the first map function. It should be:

```
return dict[key].map(function(v, i) {
```

Comment: that worked! Why would I have needed that extra return?

Comment: @Sam The inner `return` applies only to the inner function. The map function creates an array of values returned by the callback function. When you just call `dict[key].map` without returning the result, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: That actually solved one problem but I realized the components still aren't rendering! It's the button that rendered but none of the texts are...

Comment: @Sam What are the `ParentComponent` and the `NodeComponent`? Does it work if use just `<div>{v}</div>` instead?